# Basic jQuery ajax from a third party site

Tags: jquery, ajax

#### Short Version

I am having trouble with the AJAX using jQuery.

here's my [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aBQud/5/) .. I keep getting `undefined` as the response back from the `get()`. How do I get that html from my query?

#### Long Version

At the moment this is just an idea. I found a site http://www.pin1yin1.com/ which accepts queries directly at the end of the url after the comment mark, like: `http://www.pin1yin1.com/#中文` — it returns a very good pinyin for a given hanzi.

I am considering writing a google chrome extension that would automatically ruby-ify chinese text inline in the document, like many page translation tools.

To do this, I have to interpret the results from that site. They always looks something like this:

```
<tr class="characters">
    <td><a href="/dict/zi/中">中</a></td>
    <td><a href="/dict/zi/文">文</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="pinyin">
    <td>zhōng</td>
    <td>wén</td>
</tr>
```

and I need to convert that to ruby that I could inject back into the page like:

```
<ruby>中
    <rt><a href="/dict/zi/中">zhōng</a></rt>
</ruby>
<ruby>文
    <rt><a href="/dict/zi/文">wén</a></rt>
</ruby>
```

So my question is, how do I do that? I am having trouble with the AJAX using jQuery.

here's my [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aBQud/5/) .. I keep getting `undefined` as the response back from the `get()`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @RUJordan — this is not a question about the ruby programming language, but it does involve the `<ruby>` html tag. I think you added the wrong tag, but thank you.

Comment: My apologizes, removed!

Comment: @SLaks - that looks like it might be a problem, still I know there is a way.

Comment: @robertotomás: Within a Chrome extension, that can work.

Comment: @SLaks please flesh that comment into an answer, that works for me.

Comment: I changed the $.get() to $.ajax({type:"GET"}) and it returns a generic  'error'.   My bet is that your endpoint does not return an applicable format.

Comment: example:   i used hello and translated that.   but it sent me to this link: http://www.pin1yin1.com/#hello  I dont think that is the resource you are looking for.  NOrmally resources are JSON/XML/plain text.   Do they have an API, or an endpoint you could directly point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, you cannot read replies from a separate origin in client-side code, except with cooperation from the server.

However, Chrome extensions *can* send requests to other sites, as long as you list them in the permissions section of the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a cross site script call. Also known as XSS. This means you make a call to a domain other than the one your website is running on. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

When I run your example (which contains an error in the get url you should replace http:// http://www.pin1yin1.com with http://www.pin1yin1.com) I see the XSS in error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.pin1yin1.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: still, comment systems like that of google+, disqus, and livefyre all incorporate data across sites. there aught to be a good solution

Comment: @robertotomás: They control their own servers, and specifically allow (limited) cross-domain access.

Comment: The only way to avoid this is to make use of a proxy script on the server where your site runs. This script fetches the content and delivers it to your script. These other websites you mention are rest services and not direct url calling. They also allow some kind of cross domain calls. pin1yin1.com unfortunately doesn't

Comment: @roberto They might be using iFrames.